# How do I properly group polygons into arrays?

Tags: opengl-es, rendering

I want to render a scene in OpenGL ES, but I have  a problem.

Because there is no immediate mode in ES, and simulating immediate mode with single-polygon buffers is slow, I can't just switch textures and skip invisible polygons, so I have to group my polygons.

Here are characteristics of different polygons:

- Diffuse texture (mipmapped, lots of them).
- Lightmap texture (packed, up to 64 textures).
- Visibility.

At first I thought to group the polygons only by visibility area, but I couldn't find a way to use texture index arrays.

So, how do I properly make buffers of polygons to render?

Comment: What are you trying to render? That is, what is the nature of your scene?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will make visibility groups with texture subgroups. Quake uses 64 128x128 lightmaps, I'm going to replace them with a single 1024x1024 lightmap, since modern hardware supports textures of such size.